# Putting a TD value as its text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

Is it possible to take the value of a TD, and placing it as its text?

```
<td class="itemtd" value="58057" bgcolor="red"></td>
```

I can't seem to read the value, or even check if it exists, this is what I've tried so far, but it does not work

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.itemtd').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() != '') {
        $(this).append($(this).val());
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `<td>` elements can have a "value" attribute but it doesn't mean anything, and you can't get it via jQuery `.val()`. The "value" attribute is for the various input-oriented form elements.

Comment: I don't think `value` is a valid attribute for `td`.  If you change it to `data-value`, you can use the `$(this).data('value')` - https://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use jquery `attr` and `html` to grab the value and place it inside the tag:

```
<script>

    $(function(){
        $('.itemtd').each(function(){
            if ($(this).attr('value') != '') {
              $(this).html($(this).attr('value'));
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

TD's do not have a `value` property. If you want to set one, use a data attribute instead:

```
<td class="itemtd" data-value="58057" bgcolor="red"></td>
```

Then use `jQuery.data()` to access the property:

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $('.itemtd').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).data('value'));
  });
});
</script>
```

You don't need to append if it's the only thing you're putting in the `td`, `jQuery.html()` will suffice. You also don't need to check the contents isn't empty because if it is then it'll just put an empty string in between.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `td` elements cannot have a `value` attribute. Adding one can will make your code invalid which can lead to rendering errors. To fix this, use `data-*` attributes to store custom data in your HTML:

```
<td class="itemtd" data-value="58057" bgcolor="red"></td>
```

Then in your JS you don't need to use `each()` as you can provide a function to `text()` which acts on each matched `td` individually. Try this:

```
$('.itemtd').text(function(i, text) {
    return text == '' ? '' : text + $(this).data('value');
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/dnz3am6z/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value attribue of the TD, then call the `data` method of the element, so change
    `if ($(this).val() != '')` to      `if ($(this).data('value'))`

and then to add the value to the TD element, change:

`$(this).append($(this).val());` to 
`$(this).html($(this).data('value'));`